# Auto-update total price in shopping cart automatically with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cart, auto-update

Please help, Im new in php .. I'd like to update the shopping cart total by ajax when i change the quantity of any item ..

```html
   <input type="text" name="qty" size="5" value="<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['qty'])){ 
                echo $_SESSION['qty']; 
            } ?>" />


//This is the code of php

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['updat_cart'])){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $update_qty = "UPDATE cart SET qty = '$qty' ";
        $run_qty = mysqli_query($conn, $update_qty);
        $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
                 
        $total = $total* $qty;
           
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I have put an image but they refused it because I don't have enough reputation to put an image

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requires more than just the php code. I suggest you to learn the semantics of it before going to implement. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) is a very good example for that. Now if you know the concept which is not evident from the code you posted, the above example just needs to be tweaked to get what you are trying to do, instead of `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'` you need to have `SELECT price FROM cart WHERE id = '".$q."' and qty = '$qty'` after you change html page in the way you need. Additional reading:

1. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-bootstrap-contact-form-using-php-and-ajax--cms-23068